# iterating 2D data column-wise,processing and storing column headers in Java

Tags: java, arrays, list, loops

I have big text files, I would like to loop through the columns while doing some comparisons of the previous value and next value then store column headers associated with them in a list to be used later. Please give me some suggestions on how to solve this problem efficiently. Below is what have done so far, can't get past trying to use "for loops"! Thanks.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Projections {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String fileName= "study_panel.csv";
        File file= new File(fileName);

        // 2-dimensional list of strings
        List<List<String>> lines = new ArrayList<>();
        Scanner inputStream;
        try{
            inputStream = new Scanner(file);

            while(inputStream.hasNext()){
                String line= inputStream.next();
                String[] values = line.split(",");
                // Adds the currently parsed line to the 2-dimensional string list
                lines.add(Arrays.asList(values));
            }

            //Compare specific elements in the list
            String svalue = lines.get(3).get(1);
            String svalue2 = lines.get(3).get(2);
            if(svalue.equals(svalue2)){
                System.out.println("No recombination");
                //store column`s header in list
            }
            else{
                System.out.println("Recombination");
                //store column`s header in list
            }

            inputStream.close();
        }catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        // Iterate through the 2-dimensional data and store column headers
        int lineNo = 0;
        for(List<String> line: lines) {
            int columnNo = 0;
            String previousValue=None;
            String newValue;

            for (String value: line) {

                //Compare column elements in the 2-dimensional data

                if(previousValue.equals(newValue)){
                    System.out.println("No recombination");
                    //store column`s header in list
                }
                else{
                    System.out.println("Recombination");
                    //store column`s header in list
                }
              // System.out.println("Individual " + lineNo + " Site " + columnNo + ": " + value);
                columnNo++;
            }
            lineNo++;
        }


    }
}
```

1.Sample study data

```
ID,S1_577905,S1_1066894,S1_1293038,S1_1491834
ind1,A,A,A,A
ind2,B,B,B,B
ind3,B,B,A,A
ind4,B,A,B,B
ind5,A,A,H,A
ind6,A,-,B,B
ind7,A,B,A,H
```

2. Sample reference data

```
ID,S1_570493,S1_592115,S1_604416,S1_614892,S1_618220,S1_636801,S1_654822,S1_655362,S1_723787,S1_723892,S1_858753,S1_867194,S1_923829,S1_925667,S1_1009779,S1_1009843,S1_1010052,S1_1010123,S1_1010298,S1_1010403,S1_1029733,S1_1039046,S1_1040024,S1_1044174,S1_1044355,S1_1049540,S1_1049657,S1_1050097,S1_1050995,S1_1126726,S1_1166956,S1_1177001,S1_1185437,S1_1188610,S1_1191450,S1_1195593,S1_1195669,S1_1195782,S1_1197394,S1_1207757,S1_1207893,S1_1211271,S1_1211343,S1_1223120,S1_1223377,S1_1237046,S1_1251020,S1_1280051,S1_1280124,S1_1284151,S1_1308043,S1_1340776,S1_1341385,S1_1363675,S1_1363753,S1_1407704,S1_1410354,S1_1431655,S1_1433696,S1_1490941,S1_1507081
A,T,T,A,C,C,T,T,T,G,G,A,A,A,A,G,G,T,G,C,G,C,T,G,C,T,A,G,C,C,C,T,T,A,C,A,G,G,A,G,C,G,T,A,C,C,A,G,A,G,C,C,A,T,T,C,A,T,T,A,G,G
B,C,G,T,A,T,C,C,A,C,A,C,C,C,G,T,A,C,C,T,A,G,A,T,T,G,G,A,A,T,T,C,C,C,T,G,A,A,C,T,T,A,C,T,A,G,T,A,G,A,T,T,G,C,A,T,G,C,C,C,A,T
```

3. Sample expected results

```
ID,S1_570493,S1_592115,S1_604416,S1_614892,S1_618220,S1_636801,S1_654822,S1_655362,S1_723787,S1_723892,S1_858753,S1_867194,S1_923829,S1_925667,S1_1009779,S1_1009843,S1_1010052,S1_1010123,S1_1010298,S1_1010403,S1_1029733,S1_1039046,S1_1040024,S1_1044174,S1_1044355,S1_1049540,S1_1049657,S1_1050097,S1_1050995,S1_1126726,S1_1166956,S1_1177001,S1_1185437,S1_1188610,S1_1191450,S1_1195593,S1_1195669,S1_1195782,S1_1197394,S1_1207757,S1_1207893,S1_1211271,S1_1211343,S1_1223120,S1_1223377,S1_1237046,S1_1251020,S1_1280051,S1_1280124,S1_1284151,S1_1308043,S1_1340776,S1_1341385,S1_1363675,S1_1363753,S1_1407704,S1_1410354,S1_1431655,S1_1433696,S1_1490941,S1_1507081
ind1,T,T,A,C,C,T,T,T,G,G,A,A,A,A,G,G,T,G,C,G,C,T,G,C,T,A,G,C,C,C,T,T,A,C,A,G,G,A,G,C,G,T,A,C,C,A,G,A,G,C,C,A,T,T,C,A,T,T,A,G,G
ind2,C,G,T,A,T,C,C,A,C,A,C,C,C,G,T,A,C,C,T,A,G,A,T,T,G,G,A,A,T,T,C,C,C,T,G,A,A,C,T,T,A,C,T,A,G,T,A,G,A,T,T,G,C,A,T,G,C,C,C,A,T
ind3,C,G,T,A,T,C,C,A,C,A,C,C,C,G,T,A,C,C,T,A,G,A,T,T,G,G,A,A,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,C,C,A,T,T,C,A,T,T,A,G,G
ind4,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,C,C,A,T,T,C,A,T,T,A,G,G
ind5,T,T,A,C,C,T,T,T,G,G,A,A,A,A,G,G,T,G,C,G,C,T,G,C,T,A,G,C,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-
ind6,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,T,T,G,C,A,T,G,C,C,C,A,T
ind7,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-
```

Comment: What do you mean by 'comparisons of the previous value and next value'. Previous/next value on the same row? or the same column like -1/+1 line? Can you provide an expected result on the sample data you provided?

Comment: There are parsing libraries for CSV files. I suggest you use them rather than manual parsing.

Comment: @Barakos, thanks! Your answer was really helpful! Row-wise comparisons as you can see what am trying to solve in entirety. Bear with me, poor break download of programming problem!

Comment: @Prashant, thank you for your suggestion! I will search and learn about parsing libraries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that you do not want to use CSV libraries (in any case your csv looks pretty simple), I tried to update your code.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        String fileName= "study_panel.csv";
        File file= new File(fileName);

        // 2-dimensional list of strings
        List<List<String>> lines = new ArrayList<>();
        List<String> header = null; //Lets store the header in a seperate list
        Map<Integer, List<String>> recombinationM = new HashMap<>();
        Map<Integer, List<String>> noRecombinationM = new HashMap<>();

        Scanner inputStream;
        try{
            inputStream = new Scanner(file);

            while(inputStream.hasNext()){
                String line= inputStream.next();
                String[] values = line.split(",");

                if (header == null){
                    header= Arrays.asList(values);
                    continue;//go to the next line as header is read
                }
                // Adds the currently parsed line to the 2-dimensional string list
                lines.add(Arrays.asList(values));
            }
            inputStream.close();
        }catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        // Iterate through the 2-dimensional data and store column headers


        for (int i=0; i<lines.size(); i++) {
            List<String> recombinationHdr = new ArrayList<>();
            List<String> noRecombinationHdr = new ArrayList<>();
            for (int j=0; j<lines.get(i).size()-1; j++) {
                //Comparison
                if (lines.get(i).get(j).equals(lines.get(i).get(j + 1))) {
                    System.out.println("No recombination");
                    noRecombinationHdr.add(header.get(j));//To store the current header
                    //hdrs.add(header.get(j+1)); // To store the next header
                } else {
                    System.out.println("Recombination");
                    recombinationHdr.add(header.get(j));//To store the current header
                    //recombinationHdr.add(header.get(j+1)); // To store the next header
                }
            }
            recombinationM.put(i, recombinationHdr);
            noRecombinationM.put(i, noRecombinationHdr);
        }
        //Print maps
        System.out.println("== No Recombination ==");
        for (Map.Entry<Integer,List<String>> entry : noRecombinationM.entrySet()){
           System.out.println("Line: " + entry.getKey() + " - " + entry.getValue().toString());
        }

        System.out.println("== Recombination ==");
        for (Map.Entry<Integer,List<String>> entry : recombinationM.entrySet()){
           System.out.println("Line: " + entry.getKey() + " - " + entry.getValue());
        }
    }
```

I have introduced the header List, where the first line of the CSV (columns) is stored, so it is separated from the rest of the lines that are stored in the lines List. And I introduced the two output Maps for recombination Headers and no recombination Headers. The map key is the line number and the value of the map is a String List of headers.

There are to main parts on the code, the Scanner part where the CSV is read and inserted into the two Lists (header and lines). The second part is the List iteration and checks. I am not sure if I have understood correctly what you mean by comparison of the values based on the next/previous values and I assumed that you mean that a comparison is on the same line between the current and next index of column: `if (lines.get(i).get(j).equals(lines.get(i).get(j + 1))) {`
 so for the line i it compares the j value with the next value j+1.

Based on the above evaluation, the line and header `header.get(j)` is stored into the recombination / noRecombination map.

The result on your sample is the following:

```
== No Recombination ==
Line: 0 - [S1_577905, S1_1066894, S1_1293038, S1_1491834, S1_1564133]
Line: 1 - [S1_577905, S1_1066894, S1_1293038, S1_1491834]
Line: 2 - [S1_1491834, S1_1564133]
Line: 3 - [S1_577905, S1_1066894, S1_1293038, S1_1491834, S1_1564133]
Line: 4 - [S1_577905, S1_1491834]
Line: 5 - [S1_577905, S1_1293038, S1_1491834, S1_1564133]
Line: 6 - [S1_1293038, S1_1491834, S1_1564133]
== Recombination ==
Line: 0 - [ID]
Line: 1 - [ID, S1_1564133]
Line: 2 - [ID, S1_577905, S1_1066894, S1_1293038]
Line: 3 - [ID]
Line: 4 - [ID, S1_1066894, S1_1293038, S1_1564133]
Line: 5 - [ID, S1_1066894]
Line: 6 - [ID, S1_577905, S1_1066894]
```

If you do not want to compare the first column (ID) you can start the second loop from j=1.